# Javascript/Jquery/Moment.js calculate the number of days between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I've googled loads and read loads, and so far wasted about 3 hours on this. I can't believe its so tough.

I have a Javascript/Jquery app, I have the moment.js plugin installed.
I'm writing a POS application, and I need to calculate the difference in days between two dates, so I can warn the user that a particular returned item might be too old to be returned.

I found this code in JS which looks good and seems to be the popular way to do it, although I just couldn't get it to work

```
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
var secondDate = new Date(2008,01,22);

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() -  secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
```

I also tried this using Moment.js, which again looks really neat

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
var x = a.diff(b);
```

The latter would be my preferred technique. But in my case I get the error "oDate.diff is not a function", here's my code ...

```
todaysDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY, MM, DD');
oDate = moment(result.Order.created).format('YYYY, MM, DD');
var diffDays = oDate.diff(todaysDate, 'days');
```

I suspect the problem is to do with the format of the oDate variable. But I can't work out why.

EDIT. Incidentally I checked the value of todaysDate and oDate with console.log and they are
 todaysDate - 2016, 09, 14
 oDate - 2016, 09, 12

Any advice?
Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do no use format function before taking the difference. . .once you call format it wont be moment object anymore. format function converts it into a string.

```
todaysDate = moment(new Date());
oDate = moment(result.Order.created);
var diffDays = oDate.diff(todaysDate, 'days');
```

Comment: I did try this initially, But when I view the format of Date() and result.Order.created they are totally different. The latter is in mySQL database format like this "2016-09-12 11:33:40"

Comment: Ok this worked.. Thanks. I don;t know why it didn't when I first tried it, perhaps because I was coding at 2am last night. But thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this?

```
var startDate = new Date(2008, 01, 12);
var endDate = new Date(2008, 01, 22);
var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
var diffDays = duration.asDays();
```

Here I use `moment.duration()` and `diff()` to get the interval between the two dates duration, and then `asDays()` to get the result in days...

Comment: Ok, I just tried this suggestion using my data. This is my code     var startDate = new Date(result.Order.created);
    var endDate = new Date(); In console.log both dates were formatted the same like this "Wed Sep 14 2016 11:45:37 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)" And I get this error : "pos.js:1588 Uncaught TypeError: endDate.diff is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

You could convert date to unix timestamp (`moment.unix()`), subtract two timestamps and check duration using `moment.duration()`, it's similar to your first try

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function showDays(firstDate,secondDate){



              var startDay = new Date(firstDate);
              var endDay = new Date(secondDate);
              var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

              var millisBetween = startDay.getTime() - endDay.getTime();
              var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;

              // Round down.
              alert( Math.floor(days));

          }
```